# UI-Router doesn't get previous state on $stateChangeSuccess

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to prevent users from going to certain states (dashboard and account) on the app if they have not completed all required enrollment steps. If a user tries to access those states by direct URL input, I will redirect them back to where they are. I am doing this simple check on my `run` block to redirect the user conditionally:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) => { 
    let shouldPreventNavigationToAccountPages = fromState.name.includes('enroll') && toState.parent === 'layout';

    if (shouldPreventNavigationToAccountPages) {
      redirectUser();
    }
}
```

So if a user comes from a "enroll" state (say "enroll.step-one") and tries to access a "layout" state they are not allowed to, they should be redirected. However, when I input the URL directly (no click on link), "fromState"returns the following object:

```
{name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true}
```

I don't have access to the previous state and cannot perform the check on `fromState.name.includes('enroll')`. Is this a default behavior in UI-Router? Is there a way to get the previous state if user tries to access a page by inputing the URL directly on browser?

Comment: could you just use `let shouldPreventNavigationToAccountPages = (!fromState.name || fromState.name.includes('enroll')) && toState.parent === 'layout';` ?

Comment: if the user accesses the state by entering URL in browser, then the app is loading from scratch and there is no previous state.

Comment: @plong0: that wouldn't work because a user could potentially try to navigate from a "layout" state to another "layout" state (say, "/dashboard" to "/account-settings") by inputting the URL and the logic you suggested would not allow it.

Comment: I think you may need to rethink how you detect if they have enrolled rather than basing it off the fromState.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to prevent users from going to certain states (dashboard and account) on the app if they have not completed all required enrollment steps.

Prevent users from going to a state by rejecting a resolver.

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
      url: "/dashboard",
      resolve: { 
          enrolled: function(enrollmentStatus) {
              if (enrollmentStatus.enrolled) {
                  return "enrolled";
              } else {
                  //throw to reject resolve
                  throw "not enrolled";
              };
          }
      },
      templateUrl: "partials/dashboard.html"
    })
```

By tracking enrollment status with a service, state changes can be rejected without regard to the previous state.

---

### UPDATE

The `$stateChangeError` event can be used to handle the rejection.

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
  if (error && fromState.name=='') {
    $state.go("enroll");
  }
});
```

For more information, see [UI Router $state API Reference -- $stateChangeError](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#events_$statechangeerror)

Comment: In case the user is not enrolled the user will have no indication of what went wrong (blank page). You could perform `$state.go('error')` and then return `$q.reject()` in your `else` statement

Comment: @MuliYulzary See update about using the $stateChangeError event

Comment: I found a different solution (a different check) that is specific to the app I am working on (not a general solution that I could post here) but I will still try to implement this when I have some time. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. All you were missing is:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) => { 
    let shouldPreventNavigationToAccountPages = fromState.name.includes('enroll') && toState.parent === 'layout';
    if (shouldPreventNavigationToAccountPages) {
      //This
      event.preventDefault();
      redirectUser();
    }
}
```